# Magento 2 : how make Burger menu in 768px

Tags: magento2, menu

Magento 2 : how make Burger menu in 768px

I want make burger menu in mediaquery 768px, because I have 11 category menu in nav so if already 768px, it's look messy, any body have exprience make burger menu in 768px?